# Can configured values be injected from both externalized Configure file and configure file that is in the app build?

Tags: spring-boot, properties, configuration, yaml, external

For a SpringBoot app, I have an external configure applicationA.yaml file which is not on class path (e.g. c:\config\applicationA.yaml) and also another configure applicaitionB.yaml which is in the build jar of my application. Both applicationA.yaml and applicationB.yaml are not completely same.

I only specified the applicationA.yaml as `spring.config.location` in my command line. Would key/values be injected from both applicationA.yaml and applicationB.yaml? In case of the same key, would the value injected from applicationA.yaml or applicationB.yaml?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to ask? Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: rephrased my question. Is it a bit more clear? Thanks.

Comment: No as only `applicationA.yaml` is loaded as that is the only explicit one you decided to load. If you want to load that additionally use `spring.config.additional-location`.

Comment: thanks. How about, if I specify the folder in spring.config.location (e.g. c:\config\) where only applicationA.yaml is located. Would applicationB.yaml that is on classpath be injected?

Comment: No as now only files in that location will be scanned. Use the same property to add configuration locations.